# How to use jquery to set set input values in a table with multiple rows to text of sibling?

Tags: jquery

I have a table that looks like this with many more columns (the number is context-dependent).

```js
    $('.action-checkbox').val(
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".col-record_id").first().text().trim()
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="rowid" class="action-checkbox">
            </td>
            <td class="col-record_id">
            10
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="rowid" class="action-checkbox">
            </td>
            <td class="col-record_id">
            14
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But this sets an empty value.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not giving `val()` a callback method.  You are just executing a statement.  As such, the value of `this` is going to be whatever it is within the context of where the $('.action-checkbox') is called, rather than referring to each element found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback function to `.val()` in order to assign a value to it, returning a value. Like this:

```
$('.action-checkbox').val(function() {
  return $(this).parent().next().text().trim()
})
```

or this using `.each()`

```
$('.action-checkbox').each(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).parent().next().text().trim())
})
```

```js
$('.action-checkbox').val(function() {
  return $(this).parent().next().text().trim()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rowid" class="action-checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="col-record_id">
      10
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rowid" class="action-checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class="col-record_id">
      14
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```